# How can I get single keys in multi-item config objects using debug:config?

Tags: 8, console

For example, in drush I can run

`drush cget search_api.server.iges_solr backend_config.connector_config.port`

and get a useful answer.

(`'search_api.server.iges_solr:backend_config.connector_config.port': 8988`)

In Drupal Console, I've tried the same formatting as in the drush command, I've tried a colon between the main config item, and the sub item

(`drupal dc search_api.server.iges_solr:backend_config.connector_config.port`)

I've tried a fair number of other things, and I've read the docs to no avail.  Is it possible to do without just grepping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Drupal Console doesn't support selecting a key from a configuration object. This is clear from `drupal help debug:config` which even mention grepping.

Using grep isn't beautiful, but it works:

```
drupal debug:config system.date | grep -A1 timezone
```

does return the timezone with the first subkey. (Changing the value after A, you get more lines/the user subkey.)

I would of course prefer to get the configuration object as proper JSON and then pipe it to [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to select a key robustly, but Drupal Console doesn't support an output format option yet - see [Github issue](https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/issues/3268).

Comment: I disagree that it is clear from the docs which is why I asked the question.  There are plenty of reasons to use grep on that command besides getting the value for a single key.  For example, if you don't know the exact nomenclature of the key you are looking for.  Still, this does seem to be the right answer, and I appreciate the hint about grep options.  Cheers.